# Receiving the json data from asynctask to activity

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

in my activity onCreatemethode im excuting the asynctask as shown below,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask(ActivityPizzaCustomize.this, null).execute();
```

PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        listener.onTaskCompleted(responseJson);
    }
```

in this asynctask im getting the response for the responseJson. when i tried to send it back to the onTaskComplete methode it crashes and giving the message application has stopped.

then i have in same activity, which is im using to get the response from the asynctask.

```
@Override
public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

    try {
        List<String> crust = new ArrayList<String>();


        for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

            if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")
                    && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("1")) {
                Log.i("Crust ", object.getString("Crust"));
                crust.add(object.getString("Crust"));
            }

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

OnTaskCompleted interface

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted {
    void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson);
}
```

problem is occuring when im sending the jsonresponse back to the activity, so is there any problem with this

```
new PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask(ActivityPizzaCustomize.this, null).execute();
```

any help will be appreciated to correct this issue.

when i remove the null then it gives following error and the suggestion as shown in the image below. (im getting that suggesstion bz of OnTaskCompleted listener in PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask)

```
public PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask(Context context, OnTaskCompleted listener) {

        // API = apiURL;
        this.contxt = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Post your stack trace along with line number.

Comment: have a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719574/receiving-the-json-data-from-asynctask-to-activity

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you don't need to call super.onPostExecute.

Comment: @David why passing null?

Comment: have you implemented OnTaskCompleted  in your ActivityPizzaCustomize activity? and instead of passing null pass this as a paramater to PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask constrcutor

Comment: when i debug it throws me this exception  InvocationTargetException, doesnt show any error msg in logcat

Comment: @Amrut Bidri yes i have public class ActivityPizzaCustomize extends Activity implements OnTaskCompleted {

Comment: based on this image you posted for fixes, click on first fix add argument to match ....., this will work

Comment: @Amrut Bidri when i select 1st then it automaticall adds null. when i select the 2nd it will remove the OnTaskCompleted listener from public PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask(Context context, OnTaskCompleted listener) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ROOT CAUSE** is the interface object is null inside your asynctask;

```
OnTaskCompleted listener;
```

change the call to asynctask inside activity oncreate method as :

```
new PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask(ActivityPizzaCustomize.this, this).execute();
```

and your constrcutor must be like this:

```
public PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask(Context context, OnTaskCompleted listener)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.listener=listener;
}
```

Comment: where should i add OnTaskCompleted listener; ?

Comment: inside your PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask class

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a valid listener argument in your constructor.

Instead of

`new PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask(ActivityPizzaCustomize.this, null).execute();`

you should be passing

`new PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask(ActivityPizzaCustomize.this, listener).execute();`

assuming you have created a proper listener already.

Comment: it gives error for listener, listener cannot be resolved to a variable. what do u mean by proper listener.

Comment: You have to create a listener, not just define it. You have defined with `public interface OnTaskCompleted`, you should create it somewhere outside the method where you are calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask` like below:

```
PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask asyncTask =new PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask(new OnTaskCompleted() {

            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(Object output) {
                 ....
            }
        });
        asyncTask.execute();


      }
```

And inside your AsyncTask:

```
OnTaskCompleted listener;

public PizzaCustomizeAsyncTask(OnTaskCompleted listener) {

        this.listener = listener;
    }
```